# Polynomials over $F_{3}$ and $F_{7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

how do we write $f(x)=x^{4}-x^{3}+14x^{2}+5x+16$ over $F_{3}$?
 answer given is:over $F_{3}:x^{4}-x^{3}+14x^{2}+5x+16=x^{4}-x^{3}-x^{2}-x+1$

how do we get this?

similarly...over $F_{7}=x^{4}-x^{3}+14x^{2}+5x+16=x^{4}-x^{3}-2x+2$

how do we get it?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients are taken to be their equivalent in $\mathbb{F}_3$, every number is equivalent modulo $3$ to one of $0,1,2$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\;-1=14=5=2\pmod 3\;,\;\;16=1\pmod 3\;$ , then

$$x^4-x^3+14x^2+5x+16=x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1\pmod 3$$

Now you try the other one.

For example, why $\;-1=2\pmod 3\;$ ? Because $\;\color{red}1+2=3=0\pmod 3\implies -1\;$ is the additive inverse of $\;2\;$ .

The other ones are similar, say $\;14=2\pmod 3\iff 14-2=0\pmod 3\;$ ,and since $\;12=3\cdot 4\;$ we're done.

Answer (score 0):

$F_p$ has characteristic $p$, which means that for any element $x\in F_p$, $px=0$.  So, no matter what $x$ is, in $F_3$, $3x=0$ and $4x=3x+x=x$, etc.  This essentially means that we can interpret the coefficients of these polynomials modulo the characteristic of the field.  Note that, for example, $2x=-x$ in characteristic $3$ and $5x^2=-2x^2$ in characteristic $7$, since $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$ and $5 \equiv -2 \mod 7$.